# Best choice for multiple loop in page?

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts

My home page include five loop.

currently i use wp_query but is it optimized ? best choice with get_posts ? 
my code looks like that

```
    // First loop
    $args_dogs = array(
    'post_type' => array('animals'),
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'species',
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => 'chien',
                        ),
                  ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
);
$query_dog = new WP_Query( $args_dogs );
if ( $query_dog->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query_dog->have_posts() ) : $query_dog->the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/publication-animaux' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



// second loop
        $args_cat = array(
        'post_type' => array('animaux'),
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'tax_query' => array(
                         array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'species',
                              'field' => 'slug',
                              'terms' => 'chat',
                            ),
                      ),
        'orderby' => 'date',
    );
    $query_cat = new WP_Query( $args_cat );
    if ( $query_cat->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query_cat->have_posts() ) : $query_cat->the_post(); ?>
          <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/publication-animaux' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    // the third loop use args for display the last sticky post
      $args_sticky = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
    $query_sticky = new WP_Query( $args_sticky );

  // the four loop use args for display last posts and ignore sticky post

   $args_home = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
   );
   $query_home = new WP_Query( $args_home );

  // the five loop use args for display elements of cpt slider 
  $slider_args = array(
   'post_type' => array('slider'),
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'order' => 'DESC',//
  );
  $slider = new WP_Query($slider_args);
```

get_posts support my parameters..so, for optimize the performance, is it better to use get_posts ? and why concretely ? I have trouble grasping the real difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should you use WP\_Query vs query\_posts() vs get\_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: I have read this, but I am not sure use the better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query`, however it does have two main differences:

1. `get_posts()` just returns an array of posts, so doesn't provide methods for [a Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).
2. `get_posts()` sets the `ignore_sticky_posts` and `no_found_rows` arguments to `true`. `no_found_rows` is required for pagination, and disabling it improves performance.

#1 means means that you need to use a slightly different method for allowing the use of template tags like `the_title()`. It also means that hooks like `loop_start` and `loop_end` will not fire.

#2 means that `get_posts()` will be faster, and you don't need to worry about sticky posts, which you almost certain don't want included as part of a secondary loop.

However, you can achieve the performance of `get_posts()` with `WP_Query` simply by setting `no_found_rows` to true, and you can ignore sticky posts by setting `ignore_sticky_posts` to `true`.

So these are essentially exactly the same:

```
// WP_Query
$query_dog = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'           => 'animals',
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'tax_query'           => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'species',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'chien',
        ],
    ],
] );

while ( $query_dog->have_posts() ) : $query_dog->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/publication-animaux' );
endwhile();

wp_reset_postdata();

// get_posts
$posts_dog = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'animals',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'species',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'chien',
        ],
    ],
] );

global $post;

foreach ( $posts_dog as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); // *Must* be $post.
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/publication-animaux' );
endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Those two loops will have the exact same result, and nearly identical performance, theoretically. In the style I've written them they even have the exact same number of lines. So which one to use basically comes down entirely to which one you prefer.

The biggest difference is probably that the `WP_Query` method triggers the `loop_start` and `loop_end` hooks, which some plugins might use, you you might want to use (`loop_start` triggers on the first use of `the_post()`, and `loop_end` triggers on the last use of `have_posts()`. WordPress doesn't do anything  with them on its own.

I myself prefer `WP_Query`, simply because I find the direct use of the global `$post` variable and `setup_postdata()` to be a bit 'hack-y'. I find `get_posts()` is more appropriate when you need to query posts for something other than outputting them in a loop. `WP_Query` on the other hand mimics the behaviour of the main loop, and

Comment: If the answer helped you then please mark it as accepted so that other users can see that your question has an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough write-up, Jacob. I've bookmarked it for future reference.